# how to fix this unexpected output?

Tags: c, xcode, algorithm

I have been doing on decomposing Integers to prime numbers, but i got stucked , it s working for one prime number, but when the iteration continues then it s not working properly and I can t come up with any solution.

For example for number 12 i expect output 2^2 x 3
but instead program stops at  2^2 x and new input is expected.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int number;
    int stop = 1;
    int prime = 0;
    int sqr = 0;

    while (stop == 1) {
        /**------ERROR------ **/
        if(scanf("%d",&number) != 1 || number < 0 ){
            fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error: Chybny vstup!\n");
            return 100;}
        if(number == 0){
            stop = 0;
            break;}
        /**------DECOMPOSITION------ **/
        for (int index = 1;index <=number;){
            if(number == 1){
                //Ak sa input cislo rovna 1 tak vypise nasledovne riadky
                printf("Prvociselny rozklad cisla 1 je:\n");
                printf("1\n");
                break;}
            if(number % (index + 1) == 0){
                // ak je cislo % index +1 (pociatocna hodnota je 2) tak sa vydeli cislom index + 1
                // do prime sa ulozi dane prvocislo
                // ak je delitelne prvocislom pripocitame sqr +1
                // cyklus pokracuje s rovnakym indexom
                number = number / (index + 1);
                prime  = index + 1;
                sqr = sqr + 1;
                continue;}
            else{
                if(sqr == 1){
                    // vypise len prvocislo
                    printf("%d",prime);}
                if(sqr != 1){
                    //vypise prvocislo aj mocninu
                    printf("%d^%d", prime,sqr);}
                if(number != 1){
                    printf(" x ");}
                else{
                    printf("\n");
                    break;}
            }
            index = index + 1;
            sqr = 0;
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Aside: it is usual to place the `index = index + 1;` *inside* the `for` loop statement, not at the end of its code block.

Comment: @WeatherVane it seems he uses `continue` to  keep processing at the same iteration

Comment: Why not start index at 2 and avoid adding 1 everywhere you use it?

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title, so that other users with a similar problem can find it.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in the code:

- The special case for `number == 1` is being handled inside the loop. That special case is much easier to handle before the loop.
- Counting the exponent is mixed into the loop that updates the factor. It's much easier to use a second loop to count the exponent.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    while (1){
        /**------GET USER INPUT------ **/
        int number;
        if(scanf("%d",&number) != 1 || number < 0 ){
            fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error: Chybny vstup!\n");
            return 100;
        }

        /**------HANDLE SPECIAL CASES------ **/
        if(number == 0){
            break;
        }
        if(number == 1){
            printf("Prvociselny rozklad cisla 1 je:1\n");
            continue;
        }

        /**------DECOMPOSITION------ **/
        for (int factor = 2; factor <= number; factor++){
            int exponent = 0;
            while(number % factor == 0){
                number /= factor;
                exponent++;
            }

            if (exponent == 1){
                printf("%d", factor);}
            else if (exponent > 1){
                printf("%d^%d", factor, exponent);}

            if(exponent != 0 && number != 1){
                printf(" x ");}
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```